# Tikzpicture - Draw a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Im trying to create this graph in latex, using tikzpicture:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}] 
\node[main] (1) {$_{1,1}$ }; 
\node[main] (2) [below right of=1] {$_{2,1}$ }; 
\node[main] (3) [above right of=2]  {$_{1,2}$ }; 
\node[main] (4) [below right of=3]  {$_{2,2}$ }; 
\draw (1) to [out=45, in=135] (3);
\draw (1) to [out=135,in=45] (3);
\draw (1) to (2); 
\draw (1) to [out=193,in=59,looseness=4] (4);
\draw (2) to (3); 
\draw (2) to [out=180+45, in=135+180] (4);
\draw (2) to [out=180+135,in=180+45] (4);
\draw (3) to (4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But this is not exactly what im trying to create.
[image]

How can I add an edge that does not cross any existing edges or how can I adjust the direction of the curve or otherwise create the first graph?

Note: The initial positions of the edges should be preserved, the edge of 1,1 starting at the bottom left leads to 2,2 at the top right.

Comment: You'll get much better results by changing the line from `(1)` to `(4)` to use `out=163, in=59, looseness=2`. But honestly I'm not sure I understand your question and what you're asking specifically.

Comment: @Hans Is the sentence is correct: `the edge of 1,1 starting at the bottom left leads to 2,2 at the top right.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem should be handled by using `controls` operation.

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}] 
\node[main] (1) {$_{1,1}$ }; 
\node[main] (2) [below right of=1] {$_{2,1}$ }; 
\node[main] (3) [above right of=2]  {$_{1,2}$ }; 
\node[main] (4) [below right of=3]  {$_{2,2}$ }; 
\draw (1) to [out=45, in=135] (3);
\draw (1) to [out=135,in=45] (3);
\draw (1) to (2); 
\draw (-.32,-.2) .. controls(-2.1,1.5) and (5.4,2) .. (3.45,-.8);
\draw (2) to (3); 
\draw (2) to [out=180+45, in=135+180] (4);
\draw (2) to [out=180+135,in=180+45] (4);
\draw (3) to (4); 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You can easily move the points as your need in the line accordingly. `\draw (-.32,-.2) .. controls(-2.1,1.5) and (5.4,2) .. (3.45,-.8);` where starting point is `(-.32,-.2)` and end point is `(3.45,-.8)`. This points `(-2.1,1.5) and (5.4,2)` controls the shape of the curved line.

Answer (score 2):

No need to invoke `controls` here (but it's a nice solution). Just play with the angle from where your edge starts. Here I just used `\draw (1.-160) to...` and played with the `out` value. Also, I added `outer sep=0 pt` to your node definition.

[image: graph with edge at different angle]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,outer sep=0pt}] 
        \node[main] (1) {$_{1,1}$ }; 
        \node[main] (2) [below right of=1] {$_{2,1}$ }; 
        \node[main] (3) [above right of=2]  {$_{1,2}$ }; 
        \node[main] (4) [below right of=3]  {$_{2,2}$ }; 
        \draw (1) to [out=45, in=135] (3);
        \draw (1) to [out=135,in=45] (3);
        \draw (1) to (2); 
        \draw (1.-160) to [out=140,in=59,looseness=2] (4); % <------ HERE
        \draw (2) to (3); 
        \draw (2) to [out=180+45, in=135+180] (4);
        \draw (2) to [out=180+135,in=180+45] (4);
        \draw (3) to (4); 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```